# Paragraph break when combining tabbing and font change

Tags: fonts, paragraphs, tabbing

I have found a strange behavior when combining the `tabbing` environement with a font change. When I write the following code

```
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more
```

the `tabbing` environment DOES NOT start a new paragraph and therefore the subsequent text (more ...) is not indented.

On the other hand when I want to change to `\sf` within the `tabbing` environment as follows

```
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\textsf{
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more
```

THERE IS a paragraph break and the subsequent text is therefore written indented.

Any idea why this happen and how to circumvent it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please put personal information into your [user profile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26515/esteban-zimanyi) rather than attaching it to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents, it makes testing a lot easier. It isn't so much the font change as the group which defeats LaTeX's trivlist code detecting whether to start a paragraph.

Also it is better to use `\sffamily` rather than `\textsf` in vertical mode contexts. The easiest fix is to start the partial paragraph after the tabbing before ending the group as shown in the last example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more


blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\textsf{
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more



blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
{\sffamily
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
\mbox{}}more more more more
more more more more
more more more more

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The check for a blank line after `\end{tabbing}` fails when you enclose `tabbing` as the argument to `\textsf`, so you get an end of paragraph.

You're best served if you define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
  {\sffamily\tabbing}
  {\endtabbing}

\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\begin{tabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{tabbing}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more

blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
\begin{sftabbing}
SELECT \= * \\
FROM \> Student S \\
WHERE \> Dept = 1
\end{sftabbing}
more more more more
more more more more
more more more more

\end{document}
```

In this way, if you change your mind about how the `sftabbing` environment should be rendered, you can simply act on its definition, rather than hunting for `tabbing` through the whole document.

[image]

Comment: Dear David and Enrico Many thanks for your anwers ! That helped me a lot. Regards  Esteban

Comment: As a follow-up of the question