# indent after {\small\begin{tabbing}...\end{tabbing}}%

Tags: fontsize, tabbing

Consider the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}%
B
{\small\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}}%
B
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `pdflatex`, it produces

[image: output with shifted B]

I'm wondering what's so bad about the combination of `tabbing` and `small` that it inserts an indent whereas the tabbing environment alone does not do that?   By the way, the same applies to `\smaller` and `\textsmaller` from the package `relsize`. (I'm interested primarily in \smaller, but, as it turns out, the issue is already present with \small.) Of course, one could use `\noindent` each time you need it, but would it be possible to do this centrally, once and for all pargraphs following `{\small\begin{tabbing}...\end{tabbing}}%`?

Comment: Why not use `\begin{tabbing}\small
A
\end{tabbing}`? This will not indent the first line of text that follows the `tabbing` environment.

Comment: @leandriis that would only make the first cell of the tabbing small

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You're right. This is something I did not have in mind.

Comment: @MdAyquassar: Although this question refers to defining a new tabbing-like environment with a different fontsize, you might be interested in it: [Tabbing and font size change](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101488/134144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group around `tabbing` is the culprit. On the other hand, the suggestion of not using the group doesn't work either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{tabbing}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{tabbing}
\lipsum[3]
\small\begin{tabbing}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{tabbing}
\normalsize
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the line spacing in the paragraph preceding `tabbing` is wrong, because it uses the leading for `\small`. Using `\par\small` is not a remedy, because if `trivlist` is started in vertical mode it does differently than when called in paragraph mode.

We can instead define a specific environment that issues `\small` at the proper place and doesn't need explicitly reverting the font size. In this version, `\small` is issued when `smalltabbing` and the inner `\trivlist` have already started, so its effect will vanish at `\end{smalltabbing}` (after the matching `\endtrivlist`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

% let's get a copy of \tabbing
\let\smalltabbing\tabbing
\let\endsmalltabbing\endtabbing
% patch \smalltabbing to issue \small at the proper time
\patchcmd{\smalltabbing}{\trivlist}{\trivlist\small}{}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{tabbing}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{tabbing}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{smalltabbing}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{smalltabbing}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A further version where you can specify a font size as optional argument (default `\small`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
% let's get a copy of \tabbing
\let\x@tabbing\tabbing
\let\endxtabbing\endtabbing
% patch \x@tabbing to issue the font size command at the proper time
\patchcmd{\x@tabbing}{\trivlist}{\trivlist\x@tabbing@size}{}{}
% define `\xtabbing` with an optional argument
\newcommand{\xtabbing}[1][\small]{%
  \let\x@tabbing@size#1\relax
  \x@tabbing
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{xtabbing}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{xtabbing}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{xtabbing}[\footnotesize]
A\\
B\\
C
\end{xtabbing}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If you instead do

```
\newcommand{\xtabbing}[1][]{%
  \let\x@tabbing@size#1\relax
  \x@tabbing
}
```

calling `\begin{xtabbing}` alone would choose the current font size, so `xtabbing` would be the same as `tabbing`.

Comment: @MdAyquassar I added an extended version where you can specify the font size you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

this is unrelated to `\small` you would see the same from

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}%
B
{\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}}%
B
\end{document}
```

You can avoid the group like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}%
B
\small
\begin{tabbing}
A
\end{tabbing}
\normalsize 
B
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MdAyquassar like most latex display environments, tabbing uses a new paragraph internally but adjusts everypar so that it looks like a continuation paragraph if there is no blank line before the environment, but a group defeats that, you would see the same with enumerate or display math or ...

Comment: You can do better… What happens to a paragraph which contains `\small` at the outer level?

Comment: @egreg don't do that (or save and restore the size, but I leave that as an exercise for people stealing ticks)

Comment: @MdAyquassar I don't mind not getting a tick, it's egreg getting one that is upsetting:-)

Comment: @MdAyquassar oh no it will be fine (it's more complete than mine as well) ignore us, we just like to argue